# EF Core + MVC 6 + .NET Core RC2 - EF not returning results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, .net-core-rc2

Entity Framework Core is not returning any results.  I've been searching near and far.  I find some tutorials saying one thing and others saying another. Here is what I have so far:

**Buyer.cs**

```
[Table("DealerCustomer", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Buyer
{
    [Key]
    public int DealerCustomerKey { get; set; }
    public int DealerId { get; set; }
}
```

**BuyerContext.cs**

```
public class BuyerContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("db connection string here");
    }
    public DbSet<Buyer> Buyers { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs** > ConfigureServices function

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddDbContext<BuyerContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer("db connection string here");

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Now I am trying to load the Buyers data from my **BuyerController.cs**:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BuyersController : Controller
{
    private BuyerContext _context;

    public BuyersController(BuyerContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Buyer> Get()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("getting buyers");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_context.Buyers);
        return _context.Buyers;
    }
}
```

This is all returning empty brackets when I load the page, instead of a list of Buyers.  However there are over 1000 rows in that table (dbo.DealerCustomer).  I know I have two places adding the db connection string but tutorials kept show both ways of doing it and when I only did it in startup.cs I was getting errors about the _context.  I can make everything look pretty later, right now I just want a good connection so I have a starting place to work from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there was a timeout because one of the decimal fields was returning null.

[EF Core Timing out on null response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740148/ef-core-timing-out-on-null-response/37740199#37740199)