# EF Core Timing out on null response

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 currency columns in my table. They are in my model as:

```
public decimal MSRP { get; set; }
public decimal Invoice { get; set; }
```

I've found that when I comment those columns out everything works fine. I then went through to see what was different about them as opposed to other currency columns.  I noticed that they are the only currency columns that actually have NULL values.  Other currency columns allow NULL, but do not have any NULL columns.

I then changed them to strings and everything loaded fine.

Here is the output debug error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory:Error: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.

How do I build the model so that it reads it as a decimal but still allows nulls? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
public decimal? MSRP { get; set; }
public decimal? Invoice { get; set; }
```

Comment: Of couse @Toxicable. This is kind of nullabilty operation in c#. When you put question mark after your type it means it can be null. Or when you want to use a property that may have null value, you can use double question mark and then do what. For example: `var a=Classname.MSRP??0;` this means if MSRP is null it will replace that with 0. You can read more on this web site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: Yes I know what a nullable type is and how set them but I was wondering why this solves op's problem

Comment: Because EF is searching for a property that exactly fit that field type in database.

Comment: Do I have to add the question mark if the type is string, or just if it is a type that is not string?

Comment: Just non string types.

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding a question mark after the type allows it to accept nulls. eg:

```
public decimal? MSRP { get; set; }
public decimal? Invoice { get; set; }
```